# Python flask retrieveing multiple url parameters

Tags: python, rest, http, flask

Thanks for taking time to answer the question. I have a simple use case which I am not sure what is going wrong.

Here is the flask URL of mine:

```
http://localhost:6000/some/resource?a=1&b=2
```

Here is my flask app route:

```
@app.route('/some/resource', methods=['GET'])
def getQ():
    print request.args.get('a') # ----> prints 1
    print request.args.get('b') # ----> prints None
```

Any idea why the second print says None instead of 2?

Thanks!

Comment: Try printing `request.args` and see what's in it.

Comment: ImmutableMultiDict([('a', u'1')])

Comment: Just a shot into the blue: Is it possbile you used `curl` and did not quote the URL properly? That would strip off the `&b=2` part.

Comment: I cant believe this. @KlausD you are correct, quoting it worked since & looked like a new statement to bash. One new thing to learn every day. If you want, you can write this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Ouch---- thanks Klaus D. for jogging my memory and making me realize that yes, this was exactly my issue also.